# How can I cast a music video to Chromecast Audio?

Tags: chromecast

I have some music video files in MP4 format which I would like to play through my speakers.

- Can I cast MP4 files to a Chromecast Audio to play the sound track?
- Which formats does a Chromecast Audio support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my Android Samsung S7 it is possible to cast MP4 video files in my WLAN to my Chromecast audio using apps like Localcast or VLC.
I can also cast MP4 videos from my laptop with the Chrome browser.
Unfortunately, a Chromecast needs the Internet to start playing anything.

Answer (score 1):

From https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6279377?hl=en-CA

> Supported Audio Formats:
>
> - HE-AAC
> - LC-AAC
> - MP3
> - Vorbis
> - WAV (LPCM)
> - Opus
> - FLAC with support for high-resolution streams (24-bit/96KHz)

You can try VLC or PLEX to cast the MP4 to your Chromecast audio.